# If I've created a react ref on the parent div of a component, is it possible to get elements by class name only within that ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've created a new component, but of course it is being implemented in many other components in the same page. I wanted to know if I could get elements by classname in relation to the ref that I've created?

I've already tried to get elements by class name, but I get elements outside of the scope of what I'm trying to retrieve.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
        this.onchange = this.onchange.bind(this);
        this.componentRef = React.createRef();
    }

    onchange = (event) => {
        //This is where I'm not sure if I can get elements by classname in reference to the ref I've created
        let elements = this.componentRef.current;
    };

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.componentRef} />;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of referencing dom elements, I just referenced the state objects instead, which is quicker and cleaner.

Comment: Hi I'm trying to do exactly what you wanted to do, what do you mean by referencing the state objects instead?

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by using a query selector on that node. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
        this.onchange = this.onchange.bind(this);
        this.componentRef = React.createRef();
    }

    onchange = (event) => {
        // you can access the children components directly here
        let elements = this.componentRef.querySelectorAll('.child');
    };

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.componentRef} />;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not work. I was able to accomplish my goal a different way.